# React native gradlew clean failed

Tags: react-native, gradlew

1 configuration failure
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Illegal character in authority at index 7: file://C:\Users\jains\OneDrive\Desktop[PROJECT-NAME]\node_modules\react-native/android

I recently had upgraded rn version from 0.64.4 to latest 0.71.0-rc.1. now i am facing this issue.

Comment: what process did you use to upgrade?.

Comment: react-native-upgrade-helper. updated code manually. now have tried updating twice. I don't even have android folder on mentioned path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in 0.71.0-rc.1 and been resolved in 0.71.0-rc.3.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35472